# What do we get when we differentiate the equation of trajectory of a particle undergoing any type of motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

When we differentiate the equation of trajectory, which is basically a relation between the positions of a particle across different dimensions (x,y,z), do we get a relationship between the velocities (Vx, Vy, Vz)?
For clarity's sake, let's take the example of 2D motion:
Is it possible to find out what the velocity in the y direction is if we know it's Vx (using the eq obtained by differentiating the eq of trajectory?)

And if it is possible, then why have I never heard of this method?

Comment: If we get the velocity of the object $V$ via differentiating and we know $V_{x}$ on before hand we can get $V_{y}^2= V^{2}-V_{x}^{2}$ ( which is given by resolution of velocity vectors to get net velocity)

Comment: "the equation of trajectory (...) is basically a relation between the positions of a particle across different dimensions". Is it? I'm used to having each coordinate given as a function of time: $x = x(t)$ etc. If I differentiate each side of this equation then of course I get the velocity x-component, again as a function of $t$. But that's because this is the definition of velocity, so nothing special about it. If this is not what you mean in your question, please clarify.

Comment: First: only if the parameterisation is by arc length do we get the velocity in x and y direction.
Without |v| we do not know vy if we know vx. so what exactly is your question

Comment: Another possible interpretation of the question is to consider cases where e.g $x$ is given in terms of $y$ (and perhaps also $t$). In that case differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ indeed gives a relationship between the component velocities. See also "implicit differentiation" for a related technique.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the $x, y$ and $z$ co-ordinates of the particle as functions of time - so we have functions $x(t), y(t)$ and $z(t)$ - then we can (in principle) differentiate these three functions to get the components of its velocity:

$\displaystyle v_x = \frac {dx(t)} {dt}$ etc.

If we only know the trajectory of the particle (e.g. $y=ax^2+b$ if the particle's path is a parabola or $x^2 + y^2 = c^2$ if its path is a circle) then we know nothing about its velocity beyond the fact that its velocity vector must be in a direction that is tangential to the path at each point.

Answer (score 0):

The position vector to a particle that move on the trajectory is

$$\vec R=  \left[ \begin {array}{c} x \left( s(t) \right) \\ y
 \left( s(t) \right) \\ z \left( s(t) \right) \end {array}
 \right]$$

where s is line element

hench

$$\frac {d}{dt}\vec R=\begin{bmatrix}
    v_x \\
    v_y \\
    v_z \\
  \end{bmatrix}=v\, \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {d}{ds}}x \left( s \right) 
\\  {\frac {d}{ds}}y \left( s \right) 
\\  {\frac {d}{ds}}z \left( s \right) \end {array}
 \right]
$$

where $~v=\frac{d}{dt}s~$